# Cannot Navigate inside a frame in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a frame in `MainWindow`. I have a page called `MainPage` from which I am trying to navigate away to `another page`.

Here is my Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Lab_Lite.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Frame  x:Name="Navigator" Source="/Lab_Lite;component/Pages/MainPage.xaml" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Here is my MainPage.cs file:

```
public partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Tile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Lab_Lite_Entities db = new Lab_Lite_Entities())
        {
            MainWindow test = new MainWindow();

            string pageName = (from t in db.TypePages
                               select t)
                               .Where(t => t.Value.Replace("***", Environment.NewLine) == ((Button)sender).Content)
                               .Select(t => t.AssociatedPage)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
            test.Navigator.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/" + pageName + ".xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug my code I found that `pagename` has perfect value that I am looking for. But I cannot navigate. I am not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used frame navigation, but it seems that creating a new MainWindow and calling Navigate off it is the wrong thing to do.  You should be calling Navigate off the actual existing MainWindow.

Comment: how can I call an existing instance of MainWindow?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating all together new instane of `MainWindow` which is not in View.
Use `existing instance of MainWindow` which you can get via two approaches -

If MainWindow is `startup window`:

```
MainWindow test = (MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow;
```

Also, you can use this generic way too -

```
MainWindow test = (MainWindow)Window.GetWindow(this);
```